# Disply all passed-in keyword arguments regardless what the key is

Tags: python, keyword-argument

"Hi -
Fairly rookie Python user and attempting some exercises in Python 3.1..
I was able to write a function taking `LastName`, `Country` as parameters and using `**kwargs` to display values passed in for `state`, `salary`, `taxrate` etc.

However, as a follow up I am trying to display keyword arguments regardless of the key - which is where I am getting stuck.

Looking for just the keyword arguments to be displayed rather than the passed in values

```
def myfunction(LastName, Country,**kwargs):
    print('Name:',LastName)
    print(Country)
    result = ""
    for arg in kwargs:
        result = arg
    return result
def main():
    myfunction('Smith','USA',state="NV",salary="55k",taxrate='2.00')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am looking for an output like this:

```
Smith
USA
State   
Salary
Taxrate
```

Comment: Aside: Python 3.1 is quite old: [it first came out in 2009, over a decade ago, and hasn't had an update since version 3.1.5 came out in April, 2012](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, `kwargs` is a dict. You can treat it as such:

```
def myfunction(last_name, country, **kwargs):
    print('name =', last_name)
    print('country =', country)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, '=', value)
```

```
>>> myfunction('Smith', 'USA', state="NV", salary="55k", taxrate='2.00')
name = Smith
country = USA
state = NV
salary = 55k
taxrate = 2.00
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. To clarify, I am using 2019 3.1 in PyCharm. is that considered dated? If so, I will look for the upgrade.

Comment: Python 3.8 is the most current version. Note that PyCharm is not the same as Python - PyCharm is just a program that makes your experience coding in python more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question right, you may try this code:

```
# Returns a list in your desired format
def func(lastName, country, **kwargs):
    ret = [lastName, country]
    for key in kwargs:
        ret.append(key.capitalize())

    return ret

# Print
for i in func("", "", ...):
    print(i)
```

It basically creates a base list to which it then appends the `kwargs` keys. As you can see, `kwargs` is a dict and can be used as one

Reminder: You should upgrade to the newest version of Python (3.8.1) which can be download [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/)

Comment: Thanks! tried this version as well. To clarify, I am using 2019 3.1 in PyCharm. is that considered dated? If so, I will look for the upgrade.

Comment: PyCharm is only the IDE you write your Code in. Yes, 3.1 is outdated, I would recommend an update. Oh and please accept the answer that helped you most :) PS: I edited my code so that it returns a list which you can then print or use